# pocketsphinx batch vs continuous

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

While decoding audio file in .wav format using pocketsphinx continuous and batch the result difference was quite significant. I would like to ask :
1. Why pocketsphinx batch is generally giving good results than pocketsphinx continuous ?
2. Is there any firm explanation of how pocketsphinx batch and continuous work ?
3. While decoding using pocketsphinx continuous the cmninit values are not correct hence, I thought to loop the wav audio file and the results were quite good. Is there any way to get cmninit values automatically rather than hard coding ?
4. Out of vocabulary words are not being recognized in pocketsphinx batch. Is it not the case that the words closest to the unrecognized words are also outputted. Why is it not happening ?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Why pocketsphinx batch is generally giving good results than pocketsphinx continuous ?

Batch analyzes audio as a whole so it can properly estimate cmn values.

> 2. Is there any firm explanation of how pocketsphinx batch and continuous work ?

In the source code

> 3. While decoding using pocketsphinx continuous the cmninit values are not correct hence, I thought to loop the wav audio file and the results were quite good. Is there any way to get cmninit values automatically rather than hard coding ?

There are many advanced algorithms, for example [used by Google](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/ru//pubs/archive/43289.pdf)

> 4. Out of vocabulary words are not being recognized in pocketsphinx batch. Is it not the case that the words closest to the unrecognized words are also outputted. Why is it not happening ?

This is how speech recognition algorithm works, it requires the list of words to look for. There are modern end-to-end systems like espnet which can recognize subword units and thus can handle arbitrary vocabulary.